# Can you help identify the artist for these Taizong horse rubbings? (Characters identified: 長安市隱李月溪手搨金石章)

Tags: classical-chinese, traditional-characters, character-identification

Can you help identify the artist?  The art was framed back in 1952 by the Jean Bohem Gallery in New York City.  These are on scroll paper which is attached to something (cloth/ linen?) Beautiful Chinese rubbing of two of the Emperor's horses.  I matched up the calligraphy and I believe that portions identifies the horses, Baitiwu (白蹄烏) and Shifachi 什伐赤.  I am not able to identify the artist mark in red?  Can anyone translate that or do you recognize what it says? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PImkh.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

the characters of the picture are 长安市隐李月溪手搨金石章.it is a seal or stamp of a person whose name is 李月溪 Li Yuexi.you can google him if you want to know more.I think the two horses you mentioned are from a tomb of a chinese emperor name 李世民 Li Shimin.I heard the relievoes were sold from china since early last century.It is not good.As a chinese I think you should return the paper to my country.I am not good at english.if you can speak chinese and want to know more about this please contact me.

Comment: Thank you for the information. These are two owned pieces of art that were framed and sold by the Jean Bohne Art Dealers in NY back in 1953.  They are being reviewed by an expert in Chinese art currently for authentication.  Thank you for the translation.  I am not familiar with Li Yuexi or his work and I do not see much information on him online.   I do not speak Chinese or I would certainly contact you to ask more questions about the art.  Thank you again.

Comment: @SMT Maybe Li Yuexi is not that famous in the internet.But Li Shimin must be very famous.he is the greatest emperor in chinese history.when he was young,he leaded a lot of fights.for several times he almost die but his horses saved him again and again.some horses were died for him.for comemorate these 6 horses,Li Shimin ordered workers make 6 relievoes of these 6 horses in his tomb.Li Yuexi is famous of making rubbings.